# How to achieve top alignment in a grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make a grid layout. There are 7 items in a grid.

The layout I want to display is as following.

```
1 3 6
2 4 7
  5
```

The actual layout displayed by the above code is

```
1
2 3 
  4
  5 6
    7
```

I tried to add `self-align` for each grid, but it doesn't work. How to fix this?

```css
.fruit-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: start;
}

.fruit {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* left column */

.fruit:nth-child(1),
.fruit:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1;
}


/* middle column */

.fruit:nth-child(3),
.fruit:nth-child(4),
.fruit:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 2;
}


/* right column */

.fruit:nth-child(6),
.fruit:nth-child(7) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="fruit-grid">
  <div class="fruit">1</div>
  <div class="fruit">2</div>
  <div class="fruit">3</div>
  <div class="fruit">4</div>
  <div class="fruit">5</div>
  <div class="fruit">6</div>
  <div class="fruit">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is what you need to complete your task. Hope this helps.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* Creates 3 columns */
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto); /* Sets the minimum row height */
  gap: 10px; /* Space between grid items */
}

.grid-item:nth-child(1) { grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1; }
.grid-item:nth-child(2) { grid-row: 2; grid-column: 1; }
.grid-item:nth-child(3) { grid-row: 1; grid-column: 2; }
.grid-item:nth-child(4) { grid-row: 2; grid-column: 2; }
.grid-item:nth-child(5) { grid-row: 3; grid-column: 1; }
.grid-item:nth-child(6) { grid-row: 1; grid-column: 3; }
.grid-item:nth-child(7) { grid-row: 2; grid-column: 3; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can also use `grid-area` here that combines both the `grid-row` and `column` syntax and will be shorter. Such as: `.grid-item:nth-child(1) { grid-area: 1 / 1; } .grid-item:nth-child(2) { grid-area: 2 / 1; }`

Answer (score 2):

One easy way would be the usage of `order` here:

```css
.fruit-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.fruit {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* left column */
.fruit:nth-child(1),
.fruit:nth-child(3),
.fruit:nth-child(6){
  order: 1;
}


/* middle column */
.fruit:nth-child(2),
.fruit:nth-child(4),
.fruit:nth-child(7) {
  order: 2;
}


/* right column */
.fruit:nth-child(5) {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="fruit-grid">
  <div class="fruit">1</div>
  <div class="fruit">2</div>
  <div class="fruit">3</div>
  <div class="fruit">4</div>
  <div class="fruit">5</div>
  <div class="fruit">6</div>
  <div class="fruit">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided are a bit verbose. You don't need that much code to achieve what you want

```css
.fruit-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 columns */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* a flow column */
  text-align: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.fruit:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 1/-1; /* fill all the columns */
  grid-row: 3; /* and placed at 3rd row */
}

.fruit {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fruit-grid">
  <div class="fruit">1</div>
  <div class="fruit">2</div>
  <div class="fruit">3</div>
  <div class="fruit">4</div>
  <div class="fruit">5</div>
  <div class="fruit">6</div>
  <div class="fruit">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @tacoshy it was a typo, it should be nth-child(5) and not (6)